# How to record guitar and voice in laptop?

Tags: guitar, voice, acoustic-guitar, recording, microphones

I want to record guitar (using line cable) and my voice(using earphone's microphone) on my Dell laptop(which has only jack) both at same time. Is there any way to do it in the cheapest way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find some helpful information in the answers to this question (https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23896/16897)  or this one (https://music.stackexchange.com/q/46091/16897).

Comment: @Rockin Cowboy the links you provided are good but not relevant. I want to record both my voice while singing and guitar at the same time in my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an external sound card. See https://www.wirerealm.com/guides/top-10-best-audio-interfaces. The cheapest way is to find the cheapest one.